# IndexError: list index out of range positive check in Tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

Hi I am getting this error to checking the positive value check in the tuple, i am getting this error

```html
my_tuple = []
a=(5,6)
b=(8,9)
#print("The list is :")
my_tuple.append((a,b))
#print(my_tuple)

my_result = [sub for sub in my_tuple[0] if all(element >= 0 for element in sub)]

print(len(my_result))

#print("The result is :")
#print(my_result)
```

Comment: In your code, `my_tuple` is an empty list. You never append anything to it.

Comment: ... which means `my_tuple[0]` does not exist

Comment: you're indexing into `my_tuple` which has a length of 0

Comment: ah i made this mistake so silly sorry fo that

Comment: glad you understood your mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you uncomment all of the commented-out lines, your code runs fine with the following output:

```
The list is :
[((5, 6), (8, 9))]
2
The result is :
[(5, 6), (8, 9)]
```